# How can I merge XML files using XMLBeam into one Java object?

Tags: xml

I have a working application that loads several different types of XML files into Java objects using interface files and org.xmlbeam.XBProjector. It's all working fine. The problem now is that we need to have 'generic' versions of these files plus a client specific file to optionally add on additional configuration.

I could obviously have the projector load a generic object and a client object, but then all my existing code would now have to scan two lists. What I want to do is merge the two objects into one. Is there any way to do that?

Thanks,
Wayne

Answer (score 0):

XMLBeam has the feature of [dynamic projections](https://xmlbeam.org/refcards.html#Dynamic_Projections). With this feature you can change the XPath expressions during runtime. Maybe you can reuse your projection interfaces and "bind" the XPaths later?

Comment: That sounds like a way to change the XPATHs, but I don't need to do that. I want to treat 1-N XML files as one combined file to get one combined projection. It sounds like I need to combine the child objects myself after the fact and just loop through all the files I find.

Comment: Yes, I think you should do it the way you describe in your comment. But you can do this by reusing the same generic projection. You actually don't even need to create a projection interface. You can always use org.w3c.dom.Element as return type or parameter type of projection methods. So you need to do it yourself, but you can do it in a generic way, without knowing what elements you are actually merging.